# Como exibir uma mensagem na view através de uma viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Como criar uma mensagem através de uma viewdata para a view?

No código abaixo eu estou tentando validar se meu user for null, ela tem que exibir o erro na tela para o usuário.

Classe

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {

        try
        {


            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

            if (user == null)
            {
                ViewData["mensagem"] = "teste";
                return RedirectToPage();
            }
            else
            {
                var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ResetPassword",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                Email email = new Email(_email);
                await email.AlterarSenha(user.UserName, callbackUrl, _env.WebRootPath);

                return RedirectToPage("./ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }





        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

View:

```
 <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Esqueci minha senha</h2>
        <span>Para redefinir sua senha, basta inserir o e-mail no campo abaixo e clicar no botão </span><strong>Recuperar Senha</strong>
        @ViewData["mensagem"]
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <form method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Recuperar Senha</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: não entendi bem o que quer, mas na View basta usar em qualquer lugar que queira acessar a mensagem `<%= ViewData["mensagem"]%>`, que é exatamente o problema?

Comment: É que estou tentando passar uma mensagem para view através de uma viewdata, porém quando cai na minha condição e preenche a viewdata onde eu mando renderizar ela não exibe a mensagem

Comment: Por exemplo: Se minha condição for null no controllers ela preenche essa viewdata e mostra na tela para o usuário, só que não estou conseguindo fazer a mensagem exibir na tela para o usuário.

Comment: Pronto eu respondi a sua duvida vê se entendeu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando o seu código a seguir:

```
if (user == null)
{
    ViewData["mensagem"] = "teste";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

é feito no código um `ViewData["messagem"]` e depois um redirecionamento para o método `OnGet` dessa mesma página, então, automáticamente esse `ViewData` não vai ter valor, por causa do redirecionamento.

Como deveria fazer para solucionar esse problema, exemplo:

```
public void OnGet()
{
    if (TempData.TryGetValue("messagem", out object value))
    {
        ViewData["messagem"] = value;
    }
}

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    TempData["messagem"] = "Enviando mensagem ...";
    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

*Explicando:* o primeiro método com o nome `OnGet` server para abrir a sua página e o método `OnPost` server para resgatar informações submetidas de um formulário (`<form/>`), acho que isso é sabido. Observe no código do método `OnPost` foi utilizado o `TempData` que tem a função de repassar informações para a outra requisição, onde o método `OnGet` pergunta se existe alguma informação no `TempData` para que dai a informação seja realmente trazida para essa nova requisição. O seu erro era nesse ponto onde você criava a informação, mas, era perdida na requisição pelo comando `RedirectToPage()`.

*Finalizando:* para transmitir informações em métodos de requisição utilize o `TempData` que é um dado temporário resgatado na sua primeira requisição e `ViewData` utilizado para a própria requisição para passar informações para `View`.